# Limited Android Developer Options

Tags: android

This is all I can see. I'm running Android 4.2.1. Is something I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Have you gone to Settings > About phone and tapped the build number 7 times? What device is this?

Comment: Of course. It's a Jiayu3gs

Comment: Well, I've solved it. It seems that I had to tap the "Android version" very quickly. Very strange.

Answer (score 2):

> Is something I'm missing?

Yes. You are missing a lot of developer options. :-)

You would have to take this up with the device manufacturer. There is no general reason why you would have access to only a subset of developer options.

Comment: Then manufacturer is going to tap the build number 7 times of incoming device:)